# Post-decrement and Pre-decrement operator in C++

Tags: c++, decrement

I have the two codes as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int a = 4;
    if ( a == a--){
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
        std::cout << "HELLO"<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is: `3`

and for this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int a = 4;
    if ( a == --a){
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
        std::cout << "HELLO"<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
3
HELLO
3
```

According to [C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), increment and decrement operator (for prefix and postfix) precedes relational opertor `==`. Then the expected output for both should be same (here expected was: `3` for both), but actually it isn't.

Any help? Also if the above condition leads to undefined behavior then please explain why.

Answer (score 2):

operator precedence tells how to parse expression (*add parenthesis*), not the order of evaluation.

so `--a == b` is effectively parsed as `(--a) == b` and not `--(a == b)`.

Comment: ... or how sequence points are handled.